# How to upload APNS certificates to Telegram App Dashboard?

Tags: telegram

I have been trying to upload my APNS certificates (prod/dev) to [Telegram Dashboard](https://my.telegram.org/apps/apns_cert).

I tried with my certificates exported as CER, PEM and P12, however without success. I checked them, and I also uploaded to others Push Servers and them work.

Have someone with the same issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the apns-dev-cert.p12
(There is no need to enter a password).

The next command generates the cert in Mac’s Terminal for PEM format
(Privacy Enhanced Mail Security Certificate):

> openssl pkcs12 -in apns-dev-cert.p12 -out apns-dev-cert.pem -nodes -clcerts

Then upload .pem to Telegram Dashboard

Comment: Worked, but only for development :(

Comment: worked for both. Inputs are hidden on web by css, just disable display:none; and you will see apns inputs below google gcm